# how to set condition on two numbers entered in EditText in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have just started android studio, i am stuck on EditText that has to take two numbers as input from user. Basically it is used for a 7-segment display with two digits that is made by views. i am able to turn on the first digit when user enters the first number, but i don't know how to turn on the second digit when user enters second number in EditText.

below is the MainActivity.java code that i've tried.

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            String input = txtInput.getText().toString();
```

//below code is for when user enter 1, the 7-segment will turn 1

```
            if (txtInput.getText().toString().equals("1")) {
                view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                view2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                view3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                view4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                view5.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                view6.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                view7.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
```

[the first digit turned red as the user entered 1, how to apply this on second digit aswell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Qdr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have modified it and added an image aswell, hope its clear now

Comment: @bandanacheez check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You used `String input = txtInput.getText().toString();` but in your code there's no var with this name "txtInput", I think you mistakes and you mean `CharSequence s` in `onTextChanged` method.

However, if you wanna get the second number that is written in `onTextChanged` you can use the following

```
if( s != null && s.length >= 2) {

String secondNumber = s[1]

Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: $secondNumber") ==> this log to check for the number

}
```

then you can continue doing your if check

```
 if (secondNumber.getText().equals("8")) {
    doSomeThing();
   }
```

Comment: it is giving errors on s[1], i have a variable txtInput that i am using to take input, i just want to move to the second number (second index) and apply if on it, kindly help

Comment: What error did you get? the `s[1]` is the second number you need, take look at the method `public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s)` the s represents the value that the user typed in the edit text

Comment: it says (Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.CharSequence') when cursor is placed on s

Comment: @bandanacheez replace `s[1]` with `s.get(1)` sorry I was tried this with kotlin